# How to append ' at end of values in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import json

body = { u'username': u"aws", u'status': u'Full', u'lname': u'Singh',u'company_id': {u'displayName': u'Root'},u'person_no': u'89',u'fname': u'Aws', u'gender':2, u'userid': u'guest'}
data = json.dumps(body)
json_data = loads(data)

keylist = data.keys()
```

I have extracted the primary keys(tier 1 keys) : primary_keylist i.e

```
[u'username', u'status', u'person_no', u'gender', u'company_id', u'lname', u'fname', u'userid']
```

Now I want to append ' to  all values corresponding to tier 1 keys.

I tried:

```
  json_data[key] = json_data[key] + "'"
```

If I am using it to change single value, then it is working 
but when I am trying to update all key(in primary_keylist)

```
 for key in keylist:
    if key in primary_keylist:
       json_data[key] = json_data[key] + "'"
    else:
         pass
```

then it is not working.
How to update all the values at once?

```
 Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'
```

Comment: what's `primary_keylist`? Also, please post how you want the resulting dictionary to look like, you have a nested dictionary in there and also have a number, what should happen in those cases?

Comment: `else: pass` is useless

Comment: Does your code throws any error?

Comment: `json_data[key]` is not always a string, so you can't concatenate it with `'` without converting it to string.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard primary_keylist is the collection of tier - 1 keys. 
def check_nested_json(json_data,keylist):
      count =0;
      n_keylist = []
      new_keylist = []
      primary_keylist = []
      for key in keylist:
            count = count +1
      for i in range(0,count):
            try:
                 n_key = json_data[keylist[i]].keys()
                 n_keylist.append(keylist[i])
                 new_keylist.append(n_key)
            except AttributeError:
                  primary_keylist.append(keylist[i])
      return  primary_keylist

Comment: Please include the error that you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
primary_keylist = [u'username',u'status',u'person_no',u'gender', u'company_id', u'lname', u'fname', u'userid']

res = [key+"'" for key in keys]
```

**Output:**:

```
>>>res
[u"username'", u"status'", u"person_no'", u"gender'", u"company_id'", u"lname'", u"fname'", u"userid'"]
```

To update values in `json_data`, use the following:

```
res = {item[0]:str(item[1])+"'" for item in json_data.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> body = { u'username': u"aws", u'status': u'Full', u'lname': u'Singh',u'company_id': {u'displayName': u'Root'},u'person_no': u'89',u'fname': u'Aws', u'gender':2, u'userid': u'guest'}
>>> res = {item[0]:str(item[1])+"'" for item in body.items()}
>>> res
{u'username': "aws'", u'status': "Full'", u'person_no': "89'", u'gender': "2'", u'userid': "guest'", u'company_id': "{u'displayName': u'Root'}'", u'lname': "Singh'", u'fname': "Aws'"}
```

To take into account nested dictionaries, use the following:

```
res = {}

for item in body.items():
    if not isinstance(item[1], dict):
        res[item[0]] = str(item[1])+"'"
    else:
        res[item[0]] = {i:str(item[1][i])+"'" for i in item[1]}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{u'username': "aws'", u'status': "Full'", u'person_no': "89'", u'gender': "2'", u'userid': "guest'", u'company_id': {u'displayName': "Root'"}, u'lname': "Singh'", u'fname': "Aws'"}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.
Is there any particular reason why for loop is not good for this .

Comment: There is no reason, just that list comprehension (used in my answer) is more practical. Your problem is that you tried to add `dict` to `str` "'"., I mentioned that in a comment on your question.

Comment: By the above solution I am getting :
     u'company_id': "{u'displayName': u'Root'}' "
Please notice the ' is appending at the end of item[1]. But I want the result like 
     u'company_id':"{u'displayName': u'Root''} "
append ' at the end of Root.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Using my second example you should be able to add "'" at the end of each value, take a look at my second "Output"

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for values, only working for keys.

Comment: My second example is for values. I do not know what did you try

Comment: Are you talking about
 res = {item[0]:str(item[1])+"'" for item in json_data.items()}

Comment: By 
res = {item[0]:str(item[1])+"'" for item in json_data.items()}
I got this :
{u'username': "answer ' ", u'status': "Full Time ' ", ", u'home_domain': "{u'displayName': u'world'} ' ", u'currency_id': "{u'displayName': u'US Dollars'} ' ", u'company_id': "{u'displayName': u'Root'} ' ", u'lname': "Singh ' ", u'securityDomain': "{u'displayName': u'world'} ' ", u'fname': "Anubhav ' ", u'gender': "2 ' ", u'password': "Nothing' "}

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about, it adds "'" at the end of each value.

Comment: it is adding " ' " at the end of each value even if it is nested.
It is taking item[1] as whole and adds " ' " to its end.
In case of nested json e.g:
 u'home_domain': "{u'displayName': u'world'}" 
in this case item[0] = {home_domain}
                  item[1] = {u'displayName': u'world'}" 
So it is appending item[1] with "'"

I

Comment: Yes, because you can only concatenate strings, means "'" can be concatenated only with strings

Comment: What if I want to add " ' " to all values(even nested).

Comment: @AnubhavSingh I updated my answer to take into account nested dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
primary_keylist = [u'username', u'status', u'person_no', u'gender', u'company_id', u'lname', u'fname', u'userid']

primary_keylist = [('').join([item, "'"]) for item in primary_keylist]
```